# Display Shapefiles .shp areas and markers on Google Maps API?

Tags: api, google-maps, maps, kml, shapefile

I have [some Shapefiles](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bozkkluvct9dqw8/AACRi_2wkoTHTw28jUM6PE3ja) displaying areas and others displaying points on the map, I want to use those on my web application and use Google Maps API. How do I do that?

I've tried converting them to more managable .kml files, but I can't do it because there are no coordinates in the .dbf file (checked using Excel). I'm stuck now. Thanks.

Comment: There are coordinates in those shape files, they just aren't in the required coordinate system for google maps (-74.494848328176886,5034614.816062573343515), I can create KML from them using [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html).  Do you know what projection those shapefiles are in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As geocodezip already suggests, for the bike_sharing_places you could use [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) like this:

```
ogr2ogr -f KML bike_sharing_places.kml BIKE_SH.shp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -s_srs EPSG:3003
```

This converts your shapefile to KML and reprojects from your projection (Monte_Mario_Italy_zone_1 [EPSG:3003](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/monte-mario-italy-zone-1/)) to WGS84 (EPSG:4326), which is required for Google Maps.

In your other file (dogs_park) the file with projection information is missing. I took a guess, and it appears to be in UTM 32N ([EPSG:32632](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32632/)). So you first have to assign that projection.

```
ogr2ogr -a_srs EPSG:32632 aree_fruizione_cani_UTM.shp aree_fruizione_cani.shp
```

Then convert and reproject:

```
ogr2ogr -f KML dogs_park.kml aree_fruizione_cani_UTM.shp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -s_srs EPSG:32632
```

Comment: Thanks, that was useful, how do I know the projection? I use QGIS. And what did you mean by "took a guess"?

Comment: For shapefiles projection information is stored in *.prj. In your uploaded files there was no "aree_fruizione_cani.prj" included, so I created it, assuming (guessing) it would be UTM. There are many places to read up on projections and QGIS, for example [here](http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/proj.php) or [here](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/04/tutorial-working-with-projections-in.html).